# How to write system.out.println as a method reference?

Tags: java-8

I am iterating a Collection using foreach, I am using intelliJ IDE.

```
queue.forEach(s->{
            System.out.println(s);
        });
```

I am getting warning here that
"Can be replaced with method reference.."

can anyone suggest how can I use method reference here?

Comment: Intellij can automatically do that. Use the suggested quick fix.

Comment: Why downvotes/closes here? Question is pretty clear...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
System.out::println
```

This should do

```
queue.forEach(System.out::println);
```